# Bundle or Group Product for Digital and physical products

Tags: bundle, group

I am having issues trying to allocate a digital product as well as a physical product to be sold in a bundle or group. I have read comments above but it does not help with Shipping costs? If I add the mp3 for downloading the shipping disappears and if I change to physical I cannot attach the downloadable content.

Is there a way to get downloadable as well as physical sold together and have a shipping option?